# How to enable the snapping options for vector layer using the python programming?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, snapping

I  want to enable the snapping options for the the existing layers using python programming. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a post [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.devel/7470) of someone who developed an **Azimuth and Distance** plugin which involved using snapping. You could take a look into the source code, it might lead you to the right direction.

Here is the script from the link posted:

```
def canvasPressEvent(self,event):
    pixels=event.pos()
    snapper=QgsMapCanvasSnapper(self.canvas)
    snapped=snapper.snapToBackgroundLayers(pixels)
    if len(snapped[1])>0:
        xy=snapped[1][0].afterVertex
    else:
        #transforming pixels to x,y
        transform = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform()
        xy = transform.toMapCoordinates(pixels) #captures the clicked coordinate and transform
    self.emit(SIGNAL("finished(PyQt_PyObject)"),xy)     #return QgsPoint in a signal
```

Comment: Thank you. But i want to enable snapping options before callling this trigger action. qgis.utils.iface.actionSplitFeatures().trigger() i dont want to link up with any events. Is there any possible way to do ?

Comment: When i am trying the following piece of code i am getting the following error:  snapper = QgsMapCanvasSnapper(canvas)
snapper.setSnapSettingsForLayer(aLayer,True,SnapToVertexAndSegment,pixels,0.0001,True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsMapCanvasSnapper' object has no attribute 'setSnapSettingsForLayer' So how can i set the snapping to the layers?

Comment: Apologies but I am not experienced in this enough, hopefully others will advise.